# How to create app install ad on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I was trying to create a Facebook app install ad. Since I haven’t registered the app in the developer center, I  wanted to create it using the URL pasted on to the field. However it does not let me save it and the URL is not recognized. URL works right when I click the link directly on my phone. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Imran

Comment: I don’t think it is supposed to work this way. You need to do this properly, following the instructions, and those start with “Register your app using the App Dashboard.” https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/#short

Comment: The guide says you can paste the URL. Only disadvantage is that it promises for links and not installs which is fine for now.